# SWIFT: session.dataTaskWithURL

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am trying to follow a tutorial on Swift, but the code does not work in Swift 3. Can anyone help update the code?

```
let url = NSURL(string: path)
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!) {
    (data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    print(">>>>> \(data)")
}
```

I have tried following the suggestions by the compiler, and have changed several of the keywords. The code now looks like this:

```
let url = NSURL(string: path)
let session = URLSession.shared
let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url! as URL) {
    (data: NSData?, response: URLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    print(">>>>> \(data)")
}
```

The error message is:

> Cannot convert value of type '(NSData?, URLResponse?, NSError?) -> Void' to expected argument type '(Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void'

Source Tutorial: Build a simple weather App https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AoYTuhWZFqM&list=PLoN_ejT35AEjBQ33-L8h2IwG11amXssGk#t=540.527064

Comment: Swift 2 is not Swift 3. Don't try to follow a Swift 2 tutorial using Swift 3.

Answer (score 2):

```
let url = URL(string:path)
let session = URLSession.shared
let task = session.dataTask(with: url!) { (data:Data?, response:URLResponse?, error:Error?) in
    print()
}
```